# select random images from a folder for webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, random, webdriver

I want to uplaod an Image to twitter, I am using selenium
I have a folder where all images are located but I need to choose a random images in that folder
Thanks for your help

```
path_image = ('C:/Users/92/Desktop/python/V2/images/')

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", element)
    
    element.send_keys(random.choice(path_image))
```

the ERROR that I am getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found : D
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)
```

Comment: have you tried uploading a singular image?

Comment: yes and it's working I did like that :                                                                                `path_image = ('C:/Users/92/Desktop/python/V2/images/img.png')`      
                                                                                  
                                                                                
  `element.send_keys(path_image)`

Comment: check my answer, hopefully that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `random.choice(path)` it will return one random character from the path you gaved, not a path to an image in your images folder as the `choice()` method expects a list.

You first need to list the images in your folder :

```
import os
images = [os.path.join(path_image, f) for f in os.listdir(path_image)]
```

Then randomly chose an image in that list :

```
random.choice(images)
```

Comment: how can I give the path directly to the folder where my py file is located ? I have try this path_image = ('/images/')

Comment: `path_image` must be a string, and not a tuple. And if you want it to be relative to you python script, add a "." in front of it. Like this : `path_image = "./images"`

Comment: I am getting this error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: path is not absolute: ./images\2.png
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)`

Comment: "path is not absolute" means selenium is expecting an absolute path. You apparently can't use a relative path as I showed you in my previous comment. You must provide your full path `path_images = "C:/Users/92/Desktop/python/V2/images/"`